# How to parse email data to Python using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, html, email, parsing, jupyter-notebook

How can I parse email data in Python using Jupyter Notebook?

Example:

```html
From: abc xyz <abc.xyz@gmail.com>

HTML :
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left:120.0pt;text-indent:-120.0pt;tab-stops:
120.0pt;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none"><b><span style="color:black">
From:<span style="mso-tab-count:1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span></b><span style="color:black">abc xyz &lt;abc.xyz@gmail.com&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

I tried the below syntax but was not able to get the desired output.

```py
for p in soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class': 'MsoNormal'}):
    for tds in p.findAll('td'):
        for each in tds:
            if each.name == "p":
                if 'From' in each.text:
                    from_flag = True

            if each.name == "ul":
                if from_flag == True:
                    for span in each.findAll('span'):
                        data['From'] = span.text
                        from_flag = False
```

Desired output: abc xyz
abc.xyz@gmail.com

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: Do you just want the email addresses?

Comment: Desired output: abc xyz <abc.xyz@gmail.com>